# Pass an empty command line through to a source'd script

Tags: bash, command-line

My bash script expects command line arguments that I parse without any problem. However the script later calls an other script which also accepts positional parameters, but providing parameters is not mandatory.

When my script `source`s the other script without arguments the other script still tries to parse those arguments that were given to my script in the first place.

I have two solutions, but none of them looks good to me.

1. With `shift`:

   ```sh
   # now making this script to handle branches:
   OPTIND=1
   while getopts "b:" opt; do
       case "$opt" in
           'b' ) branch=$OPTARG ;;
       esac
       shift
   done
   ```
2. Passing empty argument to the second script:

   ```sh
   source ${MINICONDA}/bin/activate ""
   ```

Comment: `shift $#` would be the way

Comment: Or, more simply, `set --`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this isn't needed for normal calls of a script as an external process, but only for invocations with `source` or `.`.

To provide context to readers, from bash's built-in help to `source`:

> If any arguments are supplied, they become the positional parameters when filename is executed. Otherwise the positional parameters are unchanged.

---

The easiest way to control the argument list is using `set -- arg1 arg2 ...` to immediately overwrite it with a new list. Thus:

```
orig_args=( "$@" )        # back up the original arguments
set --                    # clear the argument list

source whatever

set -- "${orig_args[@]}"  # if you ever need them back
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the description!